# Slide images from right to left not working when adding controls in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

Using material obtained on Internet I created a slide images who runs smootly from right to left, and reverse from left to right. When I added javascript next/previous controls based on w3c, I did not reach the controls working: SLIDES did not select the elements from figure with class slides.

Can someone help me to see what is wrong?
I only can use html, css, javascript.

Thanks in advance.

PS: the indentation is strange to avoid the message "you have more code than message" - condense it solved the problem.

My code:

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
var myTimer;

// NEXT AND PREVIOUS CONTROL
function plusSlides(n) {
  clearInterval(myTimer);
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");
  if (n > slides.length) { slideIndex = 1 }
  if (n < 1) { slideIndex = slides.length }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.slideContainer { max-width: 1100px; position: relative; margin: auto;}
.slideShow { overflow: hidden; height: 102px; }
.slideShow figure div { width: 20%; float: left;}
.slideShow figure img { width: 100%; float: left; }
.slideShow figure {position: relative; width: 500%; margin: 0; left: 0;
                   animation: 30s slidy infinite;}

@keyframes slidy {
     0%, 10% {left: 0%;}
    12%, 22% {left: -100%;}
    24%, 34% {left: -200%;}
    36%, 46% {left: -300%;}
    48%, 58% {left: -400%;}
    60%, 70% {left: -300%;}
    72%, 82% {left: -200%;}
    84%, 94% {left: -100%;}
    96%,100% {left: 0%;}
    }
 
.slideTxt { font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 2em;
    color: #FFF; padding: 10px 0 0 10px; position: absolute; }

.prev, .next { position: absolute; top: -20%; width: auto;
    margin-top: 4%; padding: 5px; color: #222428;
    font-weight: bold; font-size: 3em;  
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
 background-color: rgba(200,200,200, 0.4);
    }

.next {right: 0px;}
.prev {left: 0px;}

.prev:hover, .next:hover {
      color: #f2f2f2; background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); }
```

```html
<div class="slideContainer">
  <div class="slideShow">
    <figure class="slides">
      <div class="slide">
         <span class="slideTxt">1/4</span>
         <img src="https://www.4shared.com/img/eWUgvuZXiq/s25/1724ebeed78/image01" style="width: 100%;">
      </div>

      <div class="slide">
         <span class="slideTxt">2/4</span>
         <img src="https://www.4shared.com/img/Minb6_bRiq/s25/1724ebef160/image02" style="width: 100%;">
      </div>

      <div class="slide">
         <span class="slideTxt">3/4</span>
         <img src="https://www.4shared.com/img/Ef4iP6Zwiq/s25/1724ebef548/image03" style="width: 100%;">
      </div>

      <div class="slide">
         <span class="slideTxt">4/4</span>
         <img src="https://www.4shared.com/img/2InsamMSiq/s25/1724ebef930/image04" style="width: 100%;">
      </div>

      <div class="slide">
         <span class="slideTxt">5/5</span>
         <img src="https://www.4shared.com/img/eWUgvuZXiq/s25/1724ebeed78/image01" style="width: 100%;">
      </div>
    </figure>
  </div>
   
    <a class="prev" onclick='plusSlides(-1)'>&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick='plusSlides(1)'>&#10095;</a>
</div>
```

Comment: You changed the `html-tags` and `classes` in your code. The working example assigns the animation to the `.slideShow figure` selector. But in your example with the navigation arrows, this doesn't match anything. You can't just rename classes and think that CSS will find the right one itself. Either you keep the HTML structure from the example or you update the CSS selectors.

Comment: @Uchendu, thank you - your suggestion was my first try, changing the document.getElementsByClassName in JS, but the images disappeared.

Comment: @jesiperez, I recommend you to use [jquery](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_animate.asp) or [animatejs](https://animejs.com/) for the animation through javascript. I think it's possible to do it with plain javascript and css animations, but I expect that it would take a quite a moment to develop.

Comment: Why you have 2 keyframe `slidy` and `animateright` doing the same? Are they on purpose?

Comment: @Mr.Brickowski, first, I made a carousel focusing on sliding the images from right to left (keyframe slidy) - ok;  then, I tried to add controls using code from w3c, and kept the same names, changing only the content (keyframe animateright) - not ok. The code above is not the real page, just to show better the problem.